# Azure Worker Service Not Starting

Tags: c#, azure, service

I just deployed a Worker Service to Azure. Using this [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/cloud-service?pivots=visualstudio).

The problem is that it should have sent me an email by now and it hasn't so I'm assuming the Service hasn't started.

How can I tell if it's running or not?
I can go to Azure and see the Container Registry, and there's a repository in there with my Service, but I can't tell if it's actually doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

- I have followed the provided document and able to see the worker Service running
- Check the Logs for the Running status of Worker.
- Initially I can see the logs time at 12:43:59, after refresh the time has been changed

[image]

- After every refresh I can see the working status time of service is getting refreshed.

[image]

- You can see the Event status is still in a pulling state

[image]